# Change TabBadge opacity in Ionic 2

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass, ionic2

In my project I have some tabs and I want to update Badge's style when my value is 0. But I don't know how to change dynamically my tab's style. Moreover I don't know how to change the opacity of my badge in the style.

I want to have this result :

[image]

Thank you for your help ! :)

There is my code :

```
<ion-tabs color="secondary"  (ionChange)="changeTabs()">
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1" tabTitle="tab1" tabBadge="{{this.session.getToDoCount()}}" tabBadgeStyle="notif"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab2" tabTitle="tab2" tabBadge="{{this.session.getToComeCount()}}" tabBadgeStyle="notif"></ion-tab>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab3" tabTitle="tab3"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to do with ngClass directive if your badge value is zero apply a custom style.

**HTML:**

```
<ion-item class="messages">
  <ion-icon name="logo-twitter" item-left></ion-icon>
  Followers
  <ion-badge class="message" item-right [ngClass]="{'me': badgeValue === 0}">260k</ion-badge>
</ion-item>
```

**styles:**

```
.messages {
  .message {
     background: #387ef5;
     color: #fff;
  }
  .message.me {
    background: #fff;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank but I don't use an "ion-badge" balise. I use the element "tabBadge" in an ion-tab. I will update my post to explain...

Comment: @V.Pivet I never used "tabBadge" in ion-tab, but ultimately logic is same to update CSS dynamically.

Comment: I don't understand how to use ure solution in my case. It's another logic in the tabs I think ...